# Android enter key listener

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, onclicklistener

Can someone help me with a softkeyboard enter key listener?

I need a enter key listener like a button listener that would have a few editext listeners inside
like this

```
enterkey.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        if(editext1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("test1")) {
            button3.performClick();
        }
        if(editext1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("test2")) {
            button4.performClick();
        }
    }
);
```

I also need to know if something like this is correct?

```
if(editext1.getText().toString().equals.null)) {
       testwrong.setText("Wrong");
```

---

I have now tried using this code but keep getting a null value when I hit enter?
Can anyone suggest a solution to avoid this?

```
editext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if ("test1".equalsIgnoreCase(anstext.getText().toString())) {
                but4.performClick();
            }
        } else if ("test2".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
            but5.performClick();
        }
        if ("test5".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
            but6.performClick();
        }
        if ("test7".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
            but7.performClick();
        }
        if (editext.getText().toString() != null) {
            testwrong.seText("wrong");
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please format your code before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this to listen to keyboard events

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html

Comment: Please provide more than just link answers, as links can break or their content change over time

Answer (score 27):

In your `EditText` you should specify keyboard action using [imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions).

```
<EditText
       android:id="@+id/query"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:imeOptions="actionGo"
       android:inputType="text" />
```

And in your Activity's class:

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.query);
 editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to catch user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> register `onKeyListener` on your `Edittext`

```
  yourEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) { //Whenever you got user click enter. Get text in edittext and check it equal test1. If it's true do your code in listenerevent of button3
                    if("test1".equals(edt.getText().toString())) {
                        //paste your code in button3 listener here
                        }
                }

}
    )
```

This part is wrong.

> if(editext1.getText().toString().equals.null)) {
>               testwrong.setText("Wrong");

you should change to

```
if (editext1.getText().toString() != null && !editext1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
  // doSomething
}
```

Comment: I like this but how can I get if text to string in the edit text box once the enter key is pressed?

Comment: You want to get text in `EditText` at the time user press `Enter`?

Comment: I mean if edit text box has word "test1" in it while the enter key is pressed then perform a button click for button 3, thanks

Comment: I found that that I was getting a request for it to be returned, i tried the code below but the null value kept being processed when I hit enter.

Comment: @C0dexe: come to this [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people). I help you out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18223/discussion-between-c0dexe-and-yul)

Comment: Be careful the back button counts as a key. `onKey()` will intercept `onBackPressed()` and wont let you use the back button to exit the app.

Comment: Just a note that you'll want to check the action type, otherwise the code will be called twice; once on down and once on up: keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN