# Submit an AlertDialog.Builder containing an EditText by pressing enter on the keyboard in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

This is my code for an AlertDialog.Builder that has a custom view with an EditText. After entering the value inside the EditText, I want the press of Enter on the keyboard to act the same way as the PositiveButton of the AlertDialog.Builder. I have included the necessary 'imeOptions' part in the XML file. I manage to execute the code when pressing Enter, but the AlertDialog.Builder is still on screen and does not dismiss like when the PositiveButton on the AlertDialog.Builder is clicked.

```
    //AlertDialog to set weekly income
    incomeAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    incomeInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    incomeDialogView = incomeInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_weekincome, null);
    incomeAlert.setView(incomeDialogView);
    et_WeekIncome = incomeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.ls_WeekIncome);
    et_WeekIncome.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                submitIncome();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    incomeAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            submitIncome();
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE: I managed to dismiss the AlertDialog.Builder by adding another piece of code as shown below

```
        AlertDialog incomeDialog = incomeAlert.create();
        incomeDialog.show();
```

Then when needing to dismiss, I use

```
        incomeDialog.dismiss();
```

Since dismiss() is not available with AlertDialog.Builder, I had to create the Builder through an AlertDialog. Then I call dismiss() on the AlertDialog.

Thank you all for your input.

Comment: Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937731/android-enter-key-listener) maybe an [KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html) is what you'll need to handle the press on the enter button.

Comment: @vMysterion , I manage to execute the 'submitIncome' code which I want to run when enter key is pressed. But, the problem I face is that the AlertDialog.Builder does not dismiss itself, it stays on screen, but the actions needed are executed. Thanks

Comment: There is a method to dismiss an AlertDialog. I am not sure if you can call that from within the OnKeyListener. If dont, maybe try to pass the AlertDialog Context to the OnKeyListener and dismiss it with that.

Comment: I tried, dismiss() method is available for AlertDialog, I wasn't able to find a similar method for AlertDialog.Builder. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: This worked for me if I placed the onKeyListener code block after the foo.show() ; line

Comment: It has to be done after the AlertDialog is defined so that can be used in the Listener. I used setOnEditorActionListener checking EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OnKeyListener with your edit text to handle a specific keypress.

```
mEditTV.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            // do action
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, the action 'submitIncome' is being completed by the press of Enter key, but I also want the AlertDialog.Builder to dismiss, but it stays on screen unless I press the PositiveButton on it, or press back.

Comment: I solved my problem of dismissal, please check my update on the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the above **setOnKeyListener** this way.

```
et_WeekIncome.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
          case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            submitIncome();
            return true;

          default:
            break;
        }
      }return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this gives me the same result. 'submitIncome' code is executed with the press of Enter key, but the AlertDialog.Builder is still on screen.

Comment: I solved my problem of dismissal, please check my update on the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Since dismiss() is not available with AlertDialog.Builder, I had to create the Builder through an AlertDialog. Then I call dismiss() on the AlertDialog.

There is another way to deal with this problem: use the setOnShowListener callback to set the key listener.  This gives you access to the dialog's dismiss() method.

```
incomeAlert.setOnShowListener((DialogInterface d) -> {
    et_WeekIncome.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            onClick(dialog, BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            d.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```